# Is this really jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

And again this code:

```
audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    $('span#pause').fadeOut('slow');
    $('span#play').delay(1500).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

As far as I know "addEventListener" should be "bind" but somehow when I simply change it the whole script (there's more than these lines) doesn't work anymore...

Comment: addEventListener is plain javascript.

Comment: "does not work" might just be because to use `.bind`, you'd have to wrap `audioElement` into `$(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`addEventListener` is a method of the DOM element.

`fadeOut`, `fadeIn` and `delay` are jQuery methods.

If you want to use the bind method, you need a jQuery object, so it would be like

```
$(audioElement).bind('ended', function() {
    $('span#pause').fadeOut('slow');
    $('span#play').delay(1500).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: `fadeOut` etc is JavaScript too. More correct would be to say that `addEventListener` is a method of a *DOM element*.

Comment: Wow thanks. I love this question board :D. I will mark yours as right, cause your were first..

Answer (score 2):

addEventListener works on DOM elements, while bind works on jquery objects. The event handler contains JQuery code, but addEventListener is JavaScript. You could change it to:

```
$(audioElement).bind('ended', function() {
    $('span#pause').fadeOut('slow');
    $('span#play').delay(1500).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

This makes it 'full JQuery' (which is still JavaScript) :)

Answer (score 2):

The `addEventListener` is a DOM method. If you want to use the jQuery method instead, you have to wrap the DOM element in a jQuery object:

```
$(audioElement).bind('ended', function() {
  $('span#pause').fadeOut('slow');
  $('span#play').delay(1500).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to any event, including custom ones--here the listener is attached via JavaScript; it's only the code inside the function that's jQuery.